# Subtracting only Time from Datetime columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two columns of one table as `@ABC as DateTime` and `@xyz as DateTime` – Datatype.

I want to subtract only time and I am trying like this:

For `ABC = 21/02/2012 6:10:00 PM` and `XYZ = 01/01/2001 12:00:00 AM` -> 1st Row.

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), dbo.checkingtime.ABC – dbo.checkingtime.XYZ, 108)
```

and I am getting the result as `18:10`, but I want the result as `05:50` in Hours and Minutes only.

is it possible ? ? ?

Comment: How does it make sense that subtracting midnight from `6:10 pm` should result in `05:50`? It could *possibly* make sense if the subtraction was the other way around...

Comment: do you need only hours difference between tow dates?

Answer (score 1):

This is prolly a thing you want. This is built in function, but i would advise you to build your own.

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

Take note, that you will need to 'mask' start and end date with same day to get results you want (and that is time diference). The result will be in mins, but you can format it with ease to hour:min.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetTimeDifference
(
@FirstDate datetime,
@SecondDate datetime
)
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Difference INT
DECLARE @FirstTimeInMin INT
DECLARE @SecondTimeInMin INT

SELECT @FirstTimeInMin = 
(DATEPART(hour,@FirstDate) * 60 + DATEPART(minute,@FirstDate))
SELECT @SecondTimeInMin =
(DATEPART(hour,@SecondDate) * 60 + DATEPART(minute,@SecondDate))

IF @FirstTimeInMin = 0
SET @FirstTimeInMin = 24 * 60

IF @SecondTimeInMin = 0
SET @SecondTimeInMin = 24 * 60

SET @Difference = @FirstTimeInMin - @SecondTimeInMin

IF(@Difference < 0)
SET @Difference = @Difference * -1

RETURN RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @Difference / 60), 2)
 + ':' + 
RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @Difference - (@Difference / 60) * 60 ), 2)

END
GO
```

And you can use it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.GetTimeDifference('02/02/2012 6:10:00 PM','01/01/2001 12:00:00 AM')
```

It should results 05:50

Answer (score 0):

This will do,

```
select right(date2-date1,7) as time from table1
```

Result:

```
TIME
5:50AM
```

[**SQL_LIVE_DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dddf4/6)

Answer (score 0):

Here's good example I found:

```
Select start_date, end_date, time_diff,
   EXTRACT(DAY FROM time_diff) days,
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_diff) hours,
   EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time_diff) minutes,
   EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time_diff) seconds
From
(
Select start_date, end_date, end_date - start_date time_diff
From
(
Select CAST(to_date('21/02/2012 06:10:00 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mi:ss am') AS TIMESTAMP)  end_date
 , CAST(to_date('01/01/2012 12:00:00 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mi:ss am') AS TIMESTAMP) start_date
From dual
))
/
```